# libgdx sphere rotation after movement

Tags: libgdx, rotation

I'm moving my sphere on the screen using this method:

```
Matrix4 m = myBall.body.getCenterOfMassTransform();
Vector3 translation = new Vector3();
m.getTranslation(translation);

float multiplier = delta * 4 * game.platform.accelerometerFactor();
movement = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY() * multiplier, 0, Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() * multiplier);

translation.add(movement);
m.setTranslation(translation);
myBall.body.setCenterOfMassTransform(m);
```

Then I would like to rotate my sphere during movement. So I counted angle which sphere should be rotated and then applied it before I call myBall.body.setCenterOfMassTransform(m) using:

```
float x = movement.x;
float z = movement.z;
Vector3 axis = new Vector3(z, 0, -x);
m.rotate(axis, angle);
```

But the sphere is rotating strangely. Where is the problem in my process of rotation?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "strangely"? Does it rotate around your chosen axis `a = (z,0,-x)` or not?

Comment: Strangely means it does not move like in normal world when it is moving on surface. Yes it doesn't move correctly around axis = (z,0,-x)

Comment: I wonder if, depending on your multiplication conventions, the rotation is being applied with respect to the ball's local x & z axes (which wobble around as it rolls to produce a chaotic result) rather than the world's x & z axes. Switching to one of the matrix's premultiplication methods would be a way to test for this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the axis of rotation should be a positive multiple of

```
a = v x (-e_z) = (vx, vy, vz) x (0, 0, -1) = (-vy, vx, 0)
```

where `v` is the velocity vector, `e_z` the unit vector in `z` direction and `x` the vector product.